# alias to execute a comand on all files in a directory

Tags: linux, alias, csh

I want to create an alias to run a command on all the files in given directory. I am manually able to do this

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "t*.txt" -exec mycmd "{}" \;
```

However, I am having issues creating an alias for the same. I have tried several ways of escaping all the quotes and backslash.  For example:

```
alias myalias 'find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname \"t*.txt\" -exec mycmd \"{}\" \\;'
```

But I am just hitting this error

```
find: No match.
```

What am I missing?!

Comment: You are making 2 fundamental mistakes: using an alias, and using csh.  You should use a function. There are probably varieties of csh that have support for functions, and although an argument can be made that csh is acceptable for interactive use there is no justification for using an alias instead of a function.

Comment: Why is a function better than an alias for this purpose?

Comment: Functions allow more control and better visibility.  There is nothing that you can do with an alias that cannot be (better) done with a function, and no benefit to using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The following alias works fine without the need to escape anything!

```
alias myalias 'find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "t*.txt" -exec mycmd "{}" \;'
```